# Proper use case for Request VS Response with Fetch/Axios

Tags: javascript, httprequest, fetch-api

I am learning to create REST API's and use HTTP requests. It seems though that naming conventions for Request/Response is not consistent.

What I mean by all that is, many things I google regarding fetch requests. Use response as the variable name for fetch. EX: `const response = await fetch('Someurlhere.com');`

But if I am understanding correctly, that would be the request would it not?
Response should be `const response = await request.json();`

I am really just trying to make sure I am understanding everything correctly in my head of if there is a reason why there are so many resources that use my first example, which to me seems like an improper use and will just confuse new learners like myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But if I am understanding correctly, that would be the request would it not?

No. The request is what calling `fetch` triggers the browser to send to the URL. You pass the data about what the request should look like as **arguments** to `fetch`.

You could do that indirectly (which is rarely useful) by passing a [Request object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request) as an argument to `fetch`…

```
const request = new Request("http://example.com");
const response = await fetch(request);
```

… but `fetch` returns a promise that resolves as a [Response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response).

> Response should be `const response = await request.json();`

No. The promise returned from `response.json()` resolves as the result of parsing the response body as JSON.

---

You're confusing *"the response" and "something inside the response"* with *"the request" and "the response"*